# How to read large file (socket programming and python)?

Tags: python, file, sockets, io, file-transfer

I'm a beginner in socket programming and python.  I would like to learn how to send a large text file (e.g., > 5MB) from the server to client.  I keep getting an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fserver.py", line 50, in <module>
    reply = f.read()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Below is a partial of my code. Can someone take a look and give me some hints on how to resolve this issue?  Thank you for your time.

myserver.py

```
#validate filename
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    reply = f.read()
                    client.send(reply)
            #f = open(filename, 'r')
            #reply = f.read()
            #client.send(piece)
        else:
            reply = 'File not found'
            client.send(reply)
```

myclient.py

```
while True:
    print 'Enter a command: list or get <filename>'
    command = raw_input()
    if command.strip() == 'quit':
        break
    client_socket.send(command)

    data = client_socket.recv(socksize)
    print data
```

Comment: Once you fix this problem, there are a few other problems in your code. You only do one `recv` on the client, which is unlikely to get an entire file. And, even if it does, you have no way of _knowing_ whether that was the entire file or not. You probably want a slightly more complicated protocol, where you send a length first, and then the client keeps calling `recv` until it's gotten as many bytes as that length. Plus, the client needs some way to distinguish between an error, like "File not found", and actual file contents. And you need to call `sendall`, not `send`, in the server.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here has nothing to do with sockets, or with how big the file is. When you do this:

```
for line in f:
    reply = f.read()
```

The `for line in f` is trying to read one line of the file at a time, and then for each line you're trying to read the entire file. That won't work.

If you didn't get this error (which you won't in many cases), the first time through the loop you would read and ignore the first line, and then read and send everything but the first line (or, possibly, everything but the first, say, 4KB) as one giant reply, and then the loop would be done.

What you want is either one or the other:

```
for line in f:
    reply = line
```

… or  …

```
# no for loop
reply = f.read()
```

---

Meanwhile, on your client side, you're only doing one `recv`. That's going to get the first 4K (or whatever `socksize` is) or less, and then you never receive anything else.

What you need is a loop. Like this:

```
while True:
    data = client_socket.recv(socksize)
    print data
```

But now you have a new problem. Once the file is done, the client will sit there waiting forever for the next chunk of data, which will never come. So the client needs to know when it's done. And the only way it can know that is if the server puts that information into the data stream.

One way to do this is to send the length before the file. One standardized way to do this is to use the [netstring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring) protocol. You can find libraries that do this for you, but it's simple enough to do by hand. Or maybe do something more like HTTP, where the headers are just separated by newlines, and separated from the body by a blank line; then you can use `socket.makefile` as your protocol implementation. Or even a binary protocol, where you just send the length as four bytes.

There's another problem we might as well fix while we're here: `send(reply)` doesn't necessarily send the whole reply; it sends anywhere from 1 byte to the whole thing, and returns a number telling you what got sent. The simple fix to that is to use `sendall(reply)`, which guarantees to send all of it.

And finally: Your server is expecting that each `recv` will get exactly one command, as sent by `send`. But sockets don't work that way. [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html); there's nothing preventing `recv` from getting, say, just half a command, and then your server will break. So, you need some kind of protocol in that direction as well. Again, you could use netstring, or newline-separated messages, or a binary length prefix, but you have to do *something*.

(The blog post linked above has very simple example code for using binary length prefixes as a protocol.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I started without a loop, but I can only get 1024 bytes of data.  I tried the first suggestion you gave, my program compiles, but now I run into a different issue. My client does not print the whole file.  Can you point me to the right direction and let me know what I'm missing? I want to send a large text file to the client and the client can print the file on his console.

Comment: @user2203774: My comment on the question gives you some hints. I'll update the answer to elaborate. Although maybe that should be a separate question, instead of a followup here? If you still don't get it after my edit, consider creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `for line in file.readlines()`

Comment: That (a) doesn't solve his problem in any way, and (b) is bad advice. `for line in file` does the same thing, except that it doesn't try to read the whole file into memory and parse it into lines before it starts looping over them.